# Show only time labels on xAxis. Highcharts

Tags: time, highcharts, axis-labels

I need to display only time labels on xAxis. I'm using Highcharts and don't fully understand how to do it. On xAxis there should be time labels in format like 21:00. I do not need dates, only time is needed. In addition, the difference between two labels should be 00:30 (half an hour) or 01:30 and it should be zoomable. My PHP script writes some value in database every half an hour and I need to display it on a graph. Sorry for my poor English, I'm Russian. Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In xAxis of your chart you need to provide `tickinterval` and `dateTimeLabelFormats`. Following code gives the tick interval of 1.5 hours. You can change that to any number of hours you want by replacing 1.5 in `tickInterval: 1.5 * 3600 * 1000,`

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    //Sets tickInterval to 24 * 3600 * 1000 if display is by day
    tickInterval: 1.5 * 3600 * 1000,
    dateTimeLabelFormats : {
        day: '%H:%M'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You for such a quick answer! Now I have another problem - I can't understand how to make the numbers on yAxis match time labels on xAxis. Could you help me, please?

Comment: If you are using json data to bind the charts than this will help you http://www.highcharts.com/ref/show/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/series/data-array-of-name-value/

Comment: The above link retrieves a 404