# How to get multiple lines in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want a multiple line chart with Xaxis to be in 24 hour time format

In this code the xaxis is not in time format i need the xaxis to be in 24 hour time of today the time should start from 00:00(12:00 am) to end 00:00(11:59 pm)

the data would be like below array, where it has time and the count. The is in UTC time

series:

```
[
       {
  data: [
        [1369206795000, 1],
        [1369225421000, 3],
        [1369230934000, 2]
        ]},
        {
  data: [
        [1369206795000, 5],
        [1369225421000, 7],
        [1369230934000, 9]
        ]},
       {
  data: [
        [1369206795000, 4],
        [1369225421000, 6],
        [1369230934000, 9]
        ]}
        ]
```

[reference for multiple line chart](http://jsfiddle.net/19pmxa3a/1/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show only time labels on xAxis. Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328567/show-only-time-labels-on-xaxis-highcharts)

Comment: I could not add my data into chart

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show 24h range on xAxis, with tick placed every hour, set the `tickInterval` of xAxis to one hour (1000 * 60 * 60) and set `min` to start of a specific day and `max` to end of a specific day. Take a look at the example below.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.tickInterval
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.min
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.max

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/pntuz40L/